# Why does typescript not capture my type in this generic function?

Tags: typescript

The type isn't captured when using generics inside of a configuration object in some cases.

In particular, the function `functionAThatTakesAnObject` should capture the type of `aNumber` so that the type of `shouldBeInferedToBeANumber` should be `number` but instead it's given type `{}`

Any ideas why? What am I missing here? Is this a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15769)?

Here is [a typescript playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20functionA%3CT%3E(funcThatReturnsT%3A%20(something%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20T%2C%20funcThatTakeT%3A%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20something%20%3D%20undefined%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hasTypeT%20%3D%20funcThatReturnsT(something)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20funcThatTakeT(hasTypeT)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20aNumber%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20works%0D%0AfunctionA(()%20%3D%3E%20aNumber%2C%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber%20%3D%3E%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential())%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20still%20works%0D%0AfunctionA(_%20%3D%3E%20aNumber%2C%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber%20%3D%3E%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20this%20is%20the%20same%20as%20%60functionA%60%20but%20it%20takes%20a%20configuraton%20object%20instead%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Afunction%20functionAThatTakesAnObject%3CT%3E(opts%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatReturnsT%3A%20(something%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatTakeT%3A%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20any%0D%0A%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20something%20%3D%20undefined%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hasTypeT%20%3D%20opts.funcThatReturnsT(something)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20opts.funcThatTakeT(hasTypeT)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20works%0D%0AfunctionAThatTakesAnObject(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatReturnsT%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20aNumber%2C%20%2F%2F%20if%20there%20is%20no%20parameter%2C%20it%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatTakeT%3A%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber%20%3D%3E%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential()%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20DOES%20NOT%20WORK%0D%0AfunctionAThatTakesAnObject(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatReturnsT%3A%20_%20%3D%3E%20aNumber%2C%20%2F%2F%20if%20there%20is%20a%20parameter%2C%20it%20breaks%0D%0A%20%20%20%20funcThatTakeT%3A%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber%20%3D%3E%20shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential()%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

And here is the code:

```
function functionA<T>(funcThatReturnsT: (something: any) => T, funcThatTakeT: (t: T) => any) {
    let something = undefined as any;
    let hasTypeT = funcThatReturnsT(something);
    return funcThatTakeT(hasTypeT);
}

let aNumber = 5;

// works
functionA(() => aNumber, shouldBeInferedToBeANumber => shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential());
// still works
functionA(_ => aNumber, shouldBeInferedToBeANumber => shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential());

/**
 * this is the same as `functionA` but it takes a configuraton object instead
 */
function functionAThatTakesAnObject<T>(opts: {
    funcThatReturnsT: (something: any) => T,
    funcThatTakeT: (t: T) => any
}) {
    let something = undefined as any;
    let hasTypeT = opts.funcThatReturnsT(something);
    return opts.funcThatTakeT(hasTypeT);
}

// works
functionAThatTakesAnObject({
    funcThatReturnsT: () => aNumber, // if there is no parameter, it works
    funcThatTakeT: shouldBeInferedToBeANumber => shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential()
});

// DOES NOT WORK
functionAThatTakesAnObject({
    funcThatReturnsT: _ => aNumber, // if there is a parameter, it breaks
    funcThatTakeT: shouldBeInferedToBeANumber => shouldBeInferedToBeANumber.toExponential()
});
```

**Edit:**

clarification from my comment:

> I'm asking why the type isn't being inferred. I don't want to explicitly say the type. for some background, I'm writing a javascript library in typescript and the javascript users can't add that assertion so the only way the typings will work for them is if the type is inferred through usage.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, just mark the type like this:
[image]

**EDITED:**

This is another way:
[image]

**EDITED 2:** (made it compatible with JS)

[image]

Comment: thank you for you answer because that certainly gets rid of the error at the typescript side but I'm asking why the type isn't being *inferred*. I don't want to explicitly say the type. for some background, I'm writing a javascript library in typescript and the javascript users can't add that assertion so the only way the typings will work for them is if the type is inferred through usage.

Comment: I guess it gets confused with the type of the parameter which is passed in and as it becomes any due no spec of its type, it doesn't infer number and it fails the method which belongs to number type. @RicoKahler

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. `aNumber` has it's type declared so typescript shouldn't need the type of `r` to infer that the whole function returns type `number` (because the input type of a function doesn't determine the output type). I'm leaning more towards this as a bug because when I assert the type of `r` to `any` it works! but if `r` implicitly has type `any` then it breaks.

Comment: and if the intended audience of the library is javascript users, then they still can't assert the type of `r` :(

Comment: mmm I just tried to remove the type of the param passed into the func2 and it works, cause it gets inferred by any, the thing is you are giving aNumber but the funct2 can't resolve the type of this until gets called I believe, that's why it doesn't work in that way, either you specified the type of the function as number, or the parameter or in the declaration make it any, but expecting to be resolbed without being called, I dont think it works like that but I might be wrong :)